# Expected Value for a Game with Multiple Rounds

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, expected-value

I was wondering what the general approach is for calculating the expected value of a game that has multiple rounds?

For example, say in my game that I first flip a fair coin. If it's heads, then I get 10 dollars and move on to the next round. If it's tails, I pay 5 dollars and do not move onto the next round. In the second round I roll a fair 6-sided die. If it's a 1 then I get 30 dollars, otherwise I pay 10 dollars.

How should I go about calculating the expected value for playing a game like this?

Answer (score 0):

during the first round you have a $0.5$ probability of moving on to the second, and a $0.5$ probability of losing. So your expected value just based on that first round would be

$E(X)=\sum{}x*f(x)$ or $0.5*-5 +0.5*10 = 2.5$.

But since there's a second round, we need to include the expected value of the second round.

That would be $\frac{1}{6} * 30 +\frac{5}{6}* -10$, or $-3.333$.

So the final answer should be $0.5*-5 +0.5*(10-3.333) = 0.833333$.

Comment: Does the fact that I don't move onto the second round if the value is tails not impact the answer?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was out for lunch. A first round tails is factored in through the $0.5*-5$ part. So to draw it out in a sense: You have a 0.5 probability to pay 5 (tails), a $\frac{1}{2}* \frac{1}{6}$ chance to win 40 (heads, 1), and a $\frac{1}{2}* \frac{5}{6}$ chance to breakeven (heads, not 1). so your $E(X) = 0.5*-5 + \frac{1}{12} *40$ which would be 0.833.